# remove last empty line from pandas to csv using lineterminator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, series

I have a requirement where I have to split some columns as first row and the remaining as second row.

I have store them in one dataframe such as :

```
columnA   columnB   columnC   columnD
   A         B         C         D
```

to a text file `sample.txt`:

```
A,B
C,D
```

This is the code :

```
cleaned_data.iloc[:, 0:1].to_csv("report_csv.txt", encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False, line_terminator='')
cleaned_data.iloc[:,1:].to_csv("report_csv.txt", encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False, mode='a', line_terminator='')
```

It should produce as expected in `sample.txt`. However, there is third line which is empty and I dont want it to exist. I tried `lineterminator=''`, it does not work for `''` but it works such as `'  '` or `'abc'` etc..

I'm sure there is better way of producing the sample text file than using what I've written. I'm up for other alternative.

Still, how can I remove the last empty line? I'm using python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue, but it might be the case that your strings in the dataframe contain trailing line breaks. I'm running Pandas 0.23.4 on linux

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)
```

I created what I think your dataframe contains using the command

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'colA':['A'], 'colB': ['B'], 'colC':['C'], 'colD':['D']})
```

To check the contents of a cell, you could use `df['colA'][0]`.

The indexing I needed to grab the first and second columns was

```
df.iloc[:, 0:2]
```

and the way I got to a CSV did not rely on `lineterminator`

```
df.iloc[:, 0:2].to_csv("report_csv.txt", encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)
df.iloc[:,2:].to_csv("report_csv.txt", encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```

When I run

```
with open('report_csv.txt','r') as file_handle:
dat = file_handle.read()
```

I get `'A,B\nC,D\n'` from `dat`.

To get no trailing newline on the last line, use `to_string()`

```
with open('output.txt','w') as file_handle:
    file_handle.write(df.iloc[:, 0:2].to_string(header=False,index=False)+"\n")
    file_handle.write(df.iloc[:,2:].to_string(header=False,index=False))
```

Then we can verify the file is formatted as desired by running

```
with open('output.txt','r') as file_handle:
    dat = file_handle.read()
```

The `dat` contains `'A  B\nC  D'`. If spaces are not an acceptable delimiter, they could be replaced by a `,` prior to writing to file.

Comment: I'm using pandas 1.1.4... From your result, it still has `\n` at the end. My expected output is `'A,B\nC,D'`

Comment: @user6308605 - I've updated my answer with a `to_string()` approach that eliminates the trailing newline.